# Can we perform arithmetic operation in positional formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

See the program given below:

```
# Store input numbers
num1 = input('Enter first number: ')
num2 = input('Enter second number: ')

# Add two numbers
sum = float(num1) + float(num2)

# Display the sum
print('The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}'.format(num1, num2, sum))
```

Now can't we perform the sum operation inside the print statement?

I mean I know I can do this

```
a=2
b=5
print('The sum of', a ,' and ',b,' is',(a+b))
```

Like I don't need to create another sum named variable in this way. But can we perform the same thing with positional formatting?

Comment: `print('The sum of {} and {} is {}'.format(num1, num2, num1+num2))` ?

Comment: That's a good one too and thanks Jean. But guess what, not just I got the answer I wanted but Jess below in the answer section just introduced to me a totally new and amazing thing called f-strings.
Take a look- https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/

Comment: yes, Jess answer is spot on. I suggest that you accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using version 3.6 or later you can use f-strings to do this:

```
print(f'The sum of {a} and {b} is {a+b}')
```

Comment: I didn't know about f-strings and sorry if question was kind of kiddish but I have recently started to learn Python.
But thanks so much to introduce me to f-strings. Wow... I read little more about them and it's great. Thank you so so much.